# Are the end iterators always in the rhs of the comparison?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, std

From what I have found in my testing range-based standard algorithms and containers always do the following comparison `it!=c.end()` aka the end iterator is on the right of the != operator and I want to know if there's an standard or some warranty that the following will not appear on the STL implementation `c.end()!=it`

I'm curious because I'm building an iterators library and my != operator looks something like this

```
bool operator!=(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs)
{
    return lhs._validate();
}
```

Which is valid as long as the rhs is always the end iterator

Comment: The form `c.end() != it` is sometimes known as Yoda conditions, and it prevents against the typo `it = c.end()` (leaving out the !). Also, standard algorithms do not assume they work on containers, but explicitly run on a range specified by an iterator pair. That can be a sub-range of a container. (Prior to C++20 `<ranges>`)

Comment: Do that you can.

Answer (score 3):

When ever `it!=c.end()` is false, technically end iterator is on the both sides of the comparison.

There is no requirement to write `it!=c.end()` instead of `c.end()!=it` nor is there a guarantee that latter won't be written. Both are equally allowed. Furthermore it is entirely possible that neither iterator of the comparison is an end iterator: `c.begin()!=c.begin()` is perfectly fine. As such, your suggestion won't work.

Writing the changing "variable" on the left and the "constant" with a known property on the right is conventional in programming as well as natural in relation to English: We ask "Is the iterator at the end?" rather than "Is at the end the iterator?".

Comment: You are right, but I am asuming as part of the desing of my library that comparing an iterator to anything other than its end does not make much sense

Answer (score 0):

> **23.3.1 In general [iterator.requirements.general]**
> 1 Iterators are a generalization of pointers that allow a C ++ program to work with different data structures (for example, containers and ranges) in a uniform manner.
> 2 Since iterators are an abstraction of pointers, their semantics are a generalization of most of the semantics of pointers in C ++ . This ensures that every function template that takes iterators works as well with regular pointers.

Comparison of pointers is well-defined even if any of them is a null pointer or a past-the-end pointer. They have commutative property, that is result stays the same when the order of arguments is reversed. So comparison functions working with iterators are expected to behave in similar manner and not just randomly dereference arguments or require one of them not to be past-the-end iterator.

Comment: I know that comparison should be commutative, but (maybe I forgot to mention this but my iterators are input_iterators) so I am asuming that the use cases in my library do not need or require to compare an iterator to anything other thant its end because it does not make so much sense

Comment: @CarlosCM So even if iterator is supposed to be compared only with the end iterator comparison needs to be commutative. Also note that it is a good practice to write comparison with modifiable operand on the right side to avoid spurious assignment.